# Stellar-core failing to initialize history archives to S3

Tags: stellar-core, history

My archive setups are configured like this:

```
[HISTORY.v1]
get="aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/v1/{0} {1}"
put="aws s3 cp {0} s3://my-bucket/v1/{1}"
[HISTORY.v2]
get="aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/v2/{0} {1}"
[HISTORY.v3]
get="aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/v3/{0} {1}"
```

When I run `sudo stellar-core --newhist v1` I get the the following error:

```
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Process WARNING] ************
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Process WARNING]
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Process WARNING]   likely 'missing command':
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Process WARNING]
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Process WARNING]     aws s3 cp buckets/tmp/history-538feddbf840f31f/v1-stellar-history.json s3://my-bucket/v1/history/00/00/00/history-00000000.json
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Process WARNING]
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Process WARNING] ************
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Process WARNING]
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 5 for put-remote-file history/00/00/00/history-00000000.json
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 5 for put-history-archive-state
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [Work WARNING] WorkManager got FAILURE_RAISE from put-history-archive-state
2018-10-20T23:20:30.978 GBYFG [History FATAL] Failed to initialize history archive 'v1' [HistoryArchiveManager.cpp:200]
```

Not sure what the issue could be since I manually tested uploading and downloading from the same bucket.

Comment: IDK about this, but to be clear, do you mean you tested `aws s3 cp buckets/tmp/history-538feddbf840f31f/v1-stellar-history.json s3://my-bucket/v1/history/00/00/00/history-00000000.json` as `su`?

Comment: Not with that JSON file exactly but I did with a different file

Comment: To be clearer I did try to upload that file manually but it didn’t exist. So that could be the problem but it could also be a file that’s created during the initiation, which could have been cleaned up after the failed initiation